# Use Cognito locally [offline]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I've got a feeling this is a noob question... Is there a way to simulate the use of Cognito User pools locally (so offline)?

I've got a feeling that resorting to aws cognito normal user pools while developing is bit unnecessary. I now that with serverless there's a plugin to use it offline, but didn't found one for cognito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently localstack released a pro version that actually allows to run the cognito locally. It also has several other services that normally are used with cognito so this is the perfect solution for me.

https://github.com/localstack/localstack

Answer (score 26):

The AWS SDK doesn't include a local plugin for using Cognito User Pools at this time, however we have heard this request from other customers and will consider it in future releases.

Comment: that would be great :)
Thanks for the answer

Comment: Would be really awesome to see support for this from AWS.

Comment: @Ole not sure if you still need this but added an answer that might help you running this offline

Comment: Is there any news on this? It would be useful to have cognito local.

Answer (score 4):

Also there is an open source contributor created node package/docker image emulating some parts of Cognito, but not all.

https://github.com/jagregory/cognito-local

Haven't used it personally, but looking forward to it.