# dockerize reactjs app, node/express app (with AWS services)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker

I have `reactjs` application at frontend and at backend, I use `node/express` apis app.

After local development of node/express app, I deploy entire app in AWS lambda function. I user other AWS services eg. `HTTP API gateway, S3, Cognito, RDS-mysql, dynamodb`.

**Tech stack**

**Local solution**

```
Reactjs --- Node/express --- AWS services [ Cognito, S3, RDS-MYSQL, dynamodb ]
```

**Cloud Solution**

```
Reactjs ---- AWS services [ Cognito, HTTP API gateway, Lambda, S3, RDS-MYSQL, dynamodb]
```

***How to dockerize entire solution entire solution ??***

I have dockerized `reactjs app` and `node/express app`.

The part which I don't understand is how to deal with `Cognito service, S3, RDS-mysql, dynamodb` data ?

For instance in my cloud solution `login(reactjs app)` page talks to `HTTP API Gateway + Lambda` and `Lambda` talks to `AWS congnito user pool` and fetches different tokens.

In local my solution `login(Reacjs app)` page talks to `node/express api` and it talks to `Cognito service` and fetches different tokens.

Question is how to consider `cognito service (other aws services)` when it comes to dockerzing my entire cloud solution tech stack ?

Basically I want to provide **on-premise** solution.

How should I proceed ? I really have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

For services like RDS-MYSQL and dynamodb, you have to pick another database software you'll be using, that you can install inside docker, and migrate the data there (if needed). You might consider MongoDB or Redis.

For cognito, you'll have to find a replacement that works locally - a quick google search and a couple of options present themselves:

[Use Cognito locally [offline]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633800/use-cognito-locally-offline)

https://github.com/jagregory/cognito-local

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cognito-local

https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/cognito/

And for the S3 service, I believe you won't have any problems simply using on-premise storage instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no on-premise solution when you use AWS services, it's more like a hybrid solution.

Of course, you may deploy your react app and your API, but you have to set up those components (front and back) to properly work with AWS services.

To set up your components properly, you'll need to configure your AWS services for each instance or client you're working with (or if you have many development stages).

I could suggest that you could set the URLs of your services through Docker environment variables. For sure, you have to set up the proper credentials for your API and Front. Then it can reach and use those AWS services.

The following are tasks you may think about:

1. Allow your react APP to get environment variables such: API keys, tokens, credentials, service URLs, etc...
2. Allow your API to get environment variables as above.
3. Configure those to use those values instead fixed values.

That will allow you to deploy your react app and your API with multiple cognito pools, lambdas, SNS, etc...